# Как реализовать всплывающее окно в браузере?

Tags: json, php, java, delphi, c++

Доброго времени друзья. Вопрос таков: как вывести данные с моего сайта в браузер даже если человек находится на другом сайте, на ютубе к примеру? то есть, он сидит, а ему с анекдотом к примеру окошечко слева всплыло))) я хочу, к примеру, чтобы с моего сайта, мне, каждый час приходил анекдот, неважно на каком я сайте сижу, чтобы он абсолютно спозиционированный был, поверх всего ДОМ дерева и полупрозрачный. в общем какой язык мне в помощь или связка языков? плагин мне писать для браузера? или как?

Вот уже на верном пути) а путём каких языков реальзуется подобное HTML 5 Notifications API ?

Comment: > чтобы он абсолютно спозиционированный был, поверх всего ДОМ дерева и полупрозрачный

а анекдот про смс на короткий номер

Comment: вирус напишите(это шутка, не призыв к действию), или расширение и попросите ваших пользователей его поставить. ещё notify api есть, там тоже нужно разрешение пользователей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По дефолту все браузеры запрещают общение site1.com с site2.com, исключение: если они в одном домене: domsingle.site1.com и domsingle.site2.com.

Ответ: кросс-доменные запросы. 
Возможны в библиотеке jQuery.

Comment: Вот уже на верном пути) а путём каких языков реальзуется подобное HTML 5 Notifications API ?